# How to use REST API to logout a current user from the Google Cloud Identity Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/use-rest-api) explains how to use REST API to perform common user operations, such as signing in users.

But it doesn't include, how to logout the current user. How it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Identity Platform is based on firebase auth solution. The authentication is managed user-side and not server side. (the access token and the refresh token are kept in the browser memory). Therefore, you can't logout a user with a Rest API call.

However, you can redirect your user on a page that clean their browser credential and then be disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to immediately sign out another user then that cannot be done.
However, if you remove their role, revoke their permission or perform any action that will refresh their token, then they will be denied on the next action they perform, e.g. when they refresh the website, send a form, execute Cloud SDK command or make an API request.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, the required complexity makes me wonder, if providing a log-out for users is no best practice at all? So far it appeared to me like a basic requirement, that an user may log-out at any time he/she wants to leave the website or app...

Comment: Cloud Console website and Cloud SDK both have this functionality (through **Sign out** button and ```gcloud auth revoke``` command).  
If you want to implement this in your own client, then you can simply delete locally stored credentials and redirect user to a login webpage/screen.